# Recycler view not updating data with Realm data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm

I have a recycler view where I list a set of names. Above the recycler view, I have a search field where the user should be able to search for a specific name, and the recycler view should update as they type to show only the relevant results.

Here is my class:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private EditText searchField;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private MyAdapter adapter;

    private Realm realm;

    private RealmResults<Person> persons;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_persons, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        searchField = view.findViewById(R.id.search_field);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        searchField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String query = searchField.getText().toString();
                fetchPersons(query);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        fetchPersons("");

        adapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(), persons);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

        if (realm != null) {
            realm.close();
            realm = null;
        }
    }

    private void fetchPersons(String query) {
        persons = realm.where(Person.class)
                .contains("name", query)
                .findAll();
    }

}
```

However, calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` inside `onTextChanged` doesn't actually update the recycler view, so nothing ends up changing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you updating the persons variable in the adapter each time it changes? Not sure what your adapter looks like, but it seems you only pass it persons when its initialized and you never update it

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I change `persons` inside the fragment and then call the adapter to update.

Comment: Yes you update persons in the fragment, but are you sure the adapter `persons` is the same as the fragments `persons`? How are you getting the `persons` in the adapter?

Comment: `new MyAdapter(getContext(), persons)`, constructor in MyAdapter class where it sets `this.persons = persons`

Comment: right, so the adapter does not have the same persons as the fragment, it has its own persons variable you need to do something like `adapter.persons = fragment.persons` after you change the fragment.persons before calling notify dataset changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a method in adapter class to update adapter. Something as below -

```
   public void updateData(RealmResults<Person> personList) {
    this.persons = personList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Suggestion - We should keep adapter variables private and update these variable using functions only. Also notifyDataSetChanged() should called within the adapter or its functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will need to set the data in your adapter.

```java
adapter.persons.clear();
adapter.addAll(persons);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: clear and addAll for `RealmResults` is deprecated and crashes on runtime if I use them.

Comment: change the type of your data inside of the adapter to ArrayList

Comment: It must be `RealmResults` in order for it to work here

Comment: then just do `adapter.persons = persons; adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`